# Regex Question - Newbie

Tags: regex

I have the following question extracted from a textbook:

> Write a RE to describe comments consisting of a string surrounded by /* and */ without an interleaving /* or */, unless it appears between quotes “”

Here is my attempt:

```
^/[*].*(".*(/[*].*[*]/)*.*")*[*]/$
```

EDIT:

I have been using:

http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

It works on the following:

```
/* This is "/* a */" comment */fdgh
```

I'm finding it hard to debug regex's. Can you tell me where I'm going worng if the above is incorrect.

Comment: You tell us if it's right.  Does it work with your test cases?

Comment: your attempt is not the right solution..

Comment: @Gursel - How come? What is wrong with it?

Comment: Can somebody give constructive criticism/feedback?

Comment: it is not working as specified.. your regex also accepts below sample :  /* This is "/* a */" com*/ment */

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult one, after a while, I came with this solution.. It has been tested with [rad regular expression designer](http://www.radsoftware.com.au/regexdesigner/).

```
^/\*((?!.*(\*/|/\*).*\*/)[^"]*)|((?![^"]*?(\*/|/\*)")[^"]*"[^"]*"(?![^"]*?(\*/|/\*).+)[^"]*)+\*/$
```