# Regex Question - Exclude Certain Characters

Tags: java, regex

If I want to exclude /* in regex how would I write it?

I have tried:

```
[^/[*]]
([^/][^*])
```

But to no avail...

Comment: Can you give more details?  What sort of input are you expecting?  What should be captured/matched, and what shouldn't?

Comment: What programming language/regex flavor?

Comment: @ Matt Ball - Sorry, I'm using Java.

It's in relation to this post which is driving me nuts - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5937504/regex-question-newbie

Comment: In future regex questions, **please** specify the programming language/regex flavor.

Comment: BTW, I've found [this page](http://www.regexplanet.com/simple/) to be a useful tool for Java regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must match `not /`, OR `/ followed by not *`:

```
([^/]|/[^*])+/?
```

Comment: Why must the regex match no `/`s?

Comment: No, it's a trick. You match anything but `/` or a `/` followed by anything but `*`.

Comment: Is it not possible to do it in one? i.e. just ignore /* in that order??

Comment: But this will not match a `/` at the end of the string.

Answer (score 2):

Use a negative lookahead to check that, if the input contains `/`, it does not contain `/` followed by `/*`. [In JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/regexp#Special_characters_in_regular_expressions), `x` not followed by `y` would be `x(?!y)`, so:

- Either the input contains no `/`: `new RegExp('^[^/]*$')`, or
- Any `/` found must not be followed by `*`: `new RegExp('^/(?!\\*)$')` (note, the `*` must be escaped with a `\\` since `*` is a special character.

To combine the two expressions:

```
new RegExp('^([^/]|/(?!\\*))*$')
```

Comment: I was trying this, it doesn't work... all it does it capture standalone `/` characters, it doesn't get anything else. From the question it sounds like he wants everything except those.

Answer (score 0):

In Java following Pattern should work for you:

```
Pattern pt = Pattern.compile("((?<!/)[*])");
```

Which means match `*` which is NOT preceded by `/`.

#### TEST CODE

```
String str = "Hello /* World";
Pattern pt = Pattern.compile("((?<!/)[*])");
Matcher m = pt.matcher(str);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("Matched1: " + m.group(0));
}
String str1 = "Hello * World";
m = pt.matcher(str1);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("Matched2: " + m.group(0));
}
```

#### OUTPUT

```
Matched2: *
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just deny a positive match? So the kernel is just "/*", but the * needs masking by backslash, which needs masking itself, and the pattern might be followed or preceded by something, so .* before and after the `/\\*` is needed: `".*/\\*.*"`.

```
val samples = List ("*no", "/*yes", "yes/*yes", "yes/*", "no/", "yes/*yes/*yes", "n/o*")  
samples: List[java.lang.String] = List(*no, /*yes, yes/*yes, yes/*, no/, yes/*yes/*yes, n/o*)

scala> samples.foreach (s => println (s + "\t" + (! s.matches (".*/\\*.*"))))                   
*no true
/*yes   false
yes/*yes    false
yes/*   false
no/ true
yes/*yes/*yes   false
n/o*    true
```

Answer (score -1):

See http://mindprod.com/jgloss/regex.html#EXCLUSION

e.g. [^"] or [^w-z] for anything but quote and anything but wxyz

Comment: The OP already knows about negated character classes, and they don't solve the problem.