# Get the full path of all files of some types from a html file and put them into an array using js/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, string

I need to get the paths from something like this:

```
<object>
<p>https://bla-bla-bla/thing.flv</p>
</object>

<p>level/thing.mp3</p>
<ul>
<li>https://thing/otherthing/thing.srt<li></ul>
```

On the other hand, the files can be anywhere inside the html file.

I tried some possibilities, but without success.

Any clue?

Thanks a lot!

I need to get  some file names with the proper address and put them into an array:

```
myArray[0]='https://bla-bla-bla/othername.flv'
myArray[1]='/level/name.mp3'
myArray[2]='https://text/othertext/name.srt'
```

..and so on

I'm very close to solve it using regexp, I did:

```
var str = document.getElementById("content").innerHTML;

var res = str.match(/=http.*?.flv/gi);
```

In this case, I get the excerpt, but I get the whole thing around it.
eg.

I need this:

```
'https://this/otherthing/thing.srt'
```

But I  getting this

```
'more https stuff from other url ...https://this/otherthing/thing.srt even more text...'
```

uniques url's, not a giant string with the first http ending with the first .srt. I need a valid path.

Comment: Try searching for regular expressions. If the different types are known, shouldn't be too hard at all.

Comment: What? Be more clear of what you want to do. What are you looking for in the html file exactly, what have you already tried and why those didn't work

Comment: I just added more details.

Comment: I don't understand, so are the links available in text or are you trying to discover links?

Comment: Actually I need to get the files'names such as othername.flv, name.mp3 and name.srt, but these ones could be locally or in a url. So I need a generic approach in order to do it.

Comment: All the url or local file names are in the html file.

Comment: Are they randomly scattered or? How are they placed? Text? Variables? Please explain more.

Comment: They are not ramdomly inserted, they are inside <video> elements or <object> elements. I need to copy them to create a new <div> with the full downloadble list of files related to video'stuffs, such as .flv .srt. mp3 and so on.

Comment: Trying to do something like this: var res = str.match(/(?<=http).flv/gi); I know there is something wrong... but what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `.*` grabs as many matching characters as it can, you need to be more specific about what can and can't be in the middle.

Try:

```
var res = str.match(/https?:\/\/\S+\.flv/gi);
```

where `\S` grabs as many non-whitespace characters as it can.

To [exclude certain characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5937938/regex-question-exclude-certain-characters), use `[^...]`:

```
var res = str.match(/https?:\/\/[^\s;]+\.flv/gi);
```

Alternatively, just make your `.*` [lazy instead of greedy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions) with a well-placed `?`:

```
var res = str.match(/http.*?\.flv/gi);
```

Comment: OK. Very nice. I don't want ; (semicolon) in the middle.

Comment: WOW! Finally. After hours! Man I thank ou a lot for that. I'm afraid I can't give you a positive score because I'm still not allowed. But you rocked today. tks again.

Comment: Don't forget to [accept your favorite answers to your questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), even if you can't vote on them.