# Regular Expression javascript with match

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

All I need comes from

```
var str = document.getElementById("content").innerHTML;
```

I need do do this:

```
var res = str.match(/stuff_I_want - stuff_I_dont_want + final_stuff_I_want/);
```

I did this

```
var res = str.match(/=http.*?.flv/gi);
```

But there are a lot of things in between that I don't want. The result is:

```
https://http/thing.com/file.php/1/cursos/sdsdsd/sdsdsdsd/videos/video-eap-3_ertyo.srt&amp;
captions.fontsize=10&amp;
captions.state=true&amp;
file=https://dfdfdfdf.com/file.php/1/edcfr/videos/video-eap-3.flv
```

I would like to say I've opened another topic before this, but I thing people didn't understand me.

Tks everyone!

Comment: I'm sorry to have to say I don't understand this question either. Can you give some test cases of the strings which should match or not ?

Comment: what is expected output?

Comment: what is the content ?

Comment: You should give us: an example of the full input; an example of the full output; a better explanation of what is the final stuff you want.

Comment: @djjeck See his [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25212481/get-the-full-path-of-all-files-of-some-types-from-a-html-file-and-put-them-into)

Comment: This content is in a html file. I want to retrieve some paths and deliver them into an array like this:

Comment: Array[0]=https://directory_W/videos/video-eap-3.flv Array[1]=https://directory_X/videos/video-eap-3.srt Array[2]=https://directory_Y/videos/video-eap-3.mp3

Comment: You need to be more specific on the URL structure..I think this is what you want (now this only allows for `a-z`, `-`, `/`, and `.` in URLs): [`/https?:\/\/[a-z\-\/.]+?\.(flv|mp3|srt)/`](http://regex101.com/r/vO7bY4/1)

Comment: i would find the url, then use a parser on the url to extract the unencoded params

Comment: Tks everyone. I have got my answer.